# VHDL read generic default value

Tags: vhdl

I would like to know if there is a way to access an `entities default generic values` or `an entities architectures constants` during synthesis.

This is out of curiosity (and I want to implement something like that).

**Possible Usecases**

1) generating Testbench for the default entity:

```
entity testme is
    generic(outputs:integer:=4);
    ports(output:out bit_vector(0 to outputs);
end entity;
```

in the testbench i need to generate a signal whcih can be connected to output, without knowing the generics value there is no way of doing so.

2) I would like to know the actual size I use when instantiating Blockram. On FPGAs there is Blockram, fixed chunks of ram one can use, if one needs more ram than is available in one block multiple blocks are combined. Varying with the technology the size of the available blockrams can change. Thus I write an entity with two generic parameters `memory` and `technology` that implements my memory with the least Blockrams possible. This might lead to the Memory being larger than requested. If I now have another entity that needs the size of the memory to fully utilitize it (i.e. circular buffer controller), I have to supply it the actual size of the memory allocated.

Comment: I would say that you are looking at it in a way that wasn't foreseen in VHDL, and frankly I'd agree. Generaly you would propagate these values from an architecture to the instance, especially in a TB. Why would you not do it this way around?

Comment: @BennyBarns: I can't quite follow you. My Idea was glimpsing at the default value, what good is a default value for the width of a multiplexer, if i can't generate signals of the fitting widths for the output and select signals without knowing the default value?

Answer (score 0):

You have to push these things downwards from the top (ie from the testbench).  It is not possible to inspect a lower-level block (although I guess you could bring a signal out and back up to the top!)

Comment: I think there are a few legitimate uses for "out mode generics", I've occasionally wanted them too. Querying an architecture to find how many cycles deep its pipeline is, could be useful. Maybe VHDL-2020?

Comment: @BrianDrummond: No offense but then I won't be arround to use the features. Vhdl 2008 is almost 5 years old and yet most interesting stuff is not implemented.

Answer (score 0):

you can use unconstraint types, e.g.:

```
entity example
port(
    i: std_logic_vector;
    o: std_logic_vector
);
```

in the testbench you add defined vectors e.g.:

```
....
signal i,o: std_logic_vector(10 downto 0);

begin
   uut: example
   port map(
      i => i,
      o => o
   );
```

Comment: I am aware that this is possible, but I wan't to do it the other way round. The Ram problem remains.